# Apple Touch Id as PIN-code in app

Tags: ios, authorization, touch-id

So on `iOS 8` we could check that current user `IS` device owner, because he have exactly the same fingerprint. `iOS` give us `true` or `false` value.

But how can we use this value as `PIN-code` for App's authorization? For example where could we store user's `login and password`, which we could read and then use in internet-service?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that in order to use the TOUCH ID for an application is not possible. All the other ios 3rd party applications have their own 3rd party fingerprint scanning software. the TouchID software on ios is unavailable for other apps, for "Security Reasons". And the Security Reasons are that TouchID saves all its fingerprint data in the A7, or A6 chip. and does not give out that information to 3rd party applications.

Comment: sites like ebay have their servers, which store all the fingerprint information that is scanned by their own software.(not apple's)

Comment: iOS 8 opens API for using Touch Id, but it returns only `true` or `false` value. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014520-CH1

Comment: Yes, but that technology is "Still In Development"

Comment: This is a preliminary document for an API or technology in development. Apple is supplying this information to help you plan for the adoption of the technologies and programming interfaces described herein for use on Apple-branded products. This information is subject to change, and software implemented according to this document should be tested with final operating system software and final documentation. Newer versions of this document may be provided with future betas of the API or technology.

Comment: Hope you're right and Apple finally releases version, which returns unique hash for every finger, or something.

Comment: Touch ID is now available to all third parties. Example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Apple documentation for Local Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html#classes)(and as you mentioned):

Code:

```
- (void)evaluatePolicy:(LAPolicy)policy
       localizedReason:(NSString *)localizedReason
                 reply:(void (^)(BOOL success,
                                 NSError *error))reply
```

> Reply block that is executed when policy evaluation finishes. This
>   block is evaluated on a private queue internal to the framework in an
>   unspecified threading context. You must not call
>   canEvaluatePolicy:error: in this block, because doing so could lead to
>   deadlock.
>
> *success:* YES if policy evaluation succeeded, NO otherwise.

So there is not way to base your PIN, login/pass or auth-tocken on fingerprint. However you can encrypt it and store somewhere in the app's storage. So if fingerprint authentication succeeded you can use it to authorize access to the app and it's resources. Of course such tradeoff completely depend on your app's security restrictions.

What would be nice to have in Local Authentication API is ability to know that user updated(changed) fingerprints so you can request user to authenticate again. Unfortunately there is no such API.

We can also speculate if Apple may introduce hashes for fingerprint; but I think it may cause security threat if somebody steals the hash thus I do not believe we can see such API function.